# Efficient encoding of integers with constant digit sum

Tags: encoding

How can a large set of integers all with a known constant digit sum, and a constant amount of digits be encoded.

Example of integers in base 10, with digit sum 5, and 3 digits:

```
014, 041, 104, 113, 122, 131, 140, 203 ....
```

The most important factor is space, but computing time is not completely unimportant.

Comment: This set is infinite for any non-zero digit sum (203, 2003, 20003,...). Do you have a limit on the number of digits?

Comment: Yes, the number of digits is also constant.

Comment: What language are you looking to use? I've providing a solution in python below. All it's missing is the use of the permute library which is fairly straightforward.

Comment: In my current solution I use a dictionary which maps `014 -> 0`, `041 -> 2`, `104 -> 3`... and then I store the parameters needed to generate the dictionary and only store the mapped values. But I would very much like to use a non-dictionary based solution.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to store the digit sum itself, and leave it at that.

But it's possible that I misunderstand the question.

**Edit:** Here's my takeaway: You want to encode the set itself; yeah?

Encoding the set itself is as easy as storing the base, the digit sum, and the number of digits, e.g. `{10, 5, 3}` in the example you give.

Most of the time, however, you'll find that the most compact representation of a number is the number itself, unless it is very large.

Also, because digit sum is commonly taken to be recursive; and between one and nine, inclusive; 203 has the same digit sum as 500, or as 140, or as 950. This means that the set is huge for any combination of numbers, and also that any set (except for certain degenerate cases) uses every available digit in the base they are related to.

So, you know, the most efficient encoding of the numbers themselves when stored singly becomes the number itself, especially considering that every number between ±2 147 483 648 generally takes the same amount of space in memory, and often in storage.

Comment: Okay, what I need is an encoder and a decoder ( a codec ). The point is that the digit sum is always the same. If I encode 122 as it's digit sum then I will get 5, but their is no way to decode 5 back to 122.

Answer (score 0):

When you have as clearly a defined set of possible values to encode as this the straight-forward encoding theoretic approach is to sequentially number all possible values, then store this number is as many bits as necessary. This is quite clearly optimal, if the frequencies of the individual values are identical or not known. If you know something about the frequency distribution you'll instead have to use something like a Huffman code to get a truly optimal result, but that's rather complicated and I'll handle only the other case.

For the uniformly distributed (or unknown) case the approach is as follows:
Imagine (you can pre-generate and store it, or generate it on the fly) a lexicographically sorted list of all your input (for the encoding) values. E.g. in your case the list would start be (unless your digit sum is recursive): 005, 023, 032, 050, 104, 113, 122, 131, 140, 203, 212, 221, 230, 401, 410, 500.
Then assign each item in the list an integer based on its position in the list: 005 becomes 0, 023 becomes 1, 032 becomes 2 and so on. There are (unless I made a mistake, if so, adjust appropriately) 16 values in the list, for which you need 4 bits to encode any index into the list. This index is your encoded value, and encoding and decoding become obvious.

As for an algorithm to generate the list in the first place: The simplest way is to count from 000 to 999 and throw away everything that doesn't match your criterion. It *is* possible to be more clever about that by replicating counting and overflow (e.g. how 104 follows 050) but it's probably not worth the effort.